# how to paste entire column in excel vba without selecting the sheet

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I'm trying to copy the first column into the last column.  What's wrong with this code?  Getting the following error:

```
Run-time error '438
object doesn't support this property or method
```

Does vba allow `Copy` but not `paste` for columns?

```
Sub copy_ids_user_output(sheet_name As String)

'   find last column
    Dim last_col As Integer
    last_col = Worksheets(sheet_name).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column
    Debug.Print last_col

    Columns(1).Copy
    Columns(last_col + 1).Paste


End Sub
```

Comment: Are there any merged cells in the source or destination? Excel will puke on that every time you try to copy/paste.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If possible, you should avoid clobbering the user's clipboard in a macro. Just copy the column directly.

```
Columns(1).Copy Columns(last_col + 1)
```

Comment: perfect.  Like lightning.

Comment: dwstein I was also going to suggest Columns(last_col+1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll since you don't have to refer to select the sheet. This method adds to the clipboard and is two lines of code so I think Tmdean's suggestion is leaner.

Tmdean - That's cool I wasn't aware of that approach.

Comment: Yeah, the one situation I've found where you have to mess with the clipboard is when you need to paste values only. You can assign Range.Value to a variant array to assign multiple values at once, but there's a performance problem when you do that with thousands of cells.

Answer (score -2):

You should select destination and then use paste:

instead of:

```
Columns(last_col + 1).Paste
```

use

```
Columns(last_col + 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid selecting sheets, if possible.

Comment: Code selects the column, not the sheet.

Comment: You can't select a range on a sheet unless it's the active sheet.